# Finding the count of distinct values of an array and assigning them to another array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, count

I want to find the count of the distinct values of the array sorted_array.
After finding the distinct values and assigning them to the distinct_values array, I want to assign to the same position on the distinct_values_count array the count of the values, but my code doesn't seem to work. 
The output.txt file looks something like that:

> ```
> 1996
> 1983
> 1983
> 1982
> 1977
> 2011
> 1987
> 1988
> 1978
> 2012
> 2006
> 2013
> ```

```
> sorted_array = [] 
> distinct_values = []
> distinct_values_count = [0]
> file = open('output.txt', 'r')
> 
> for line in file:
>     sorted_array.append(line.split('\n'))
> 
> sorted_array.sort()
> 
> for i in range(0, len(sorted_array)):
>     year = sorted_array[i][0]
>     if year not in distinct_values:
>         distinct_values.append(year)
>     if year in distinct_values:
>         pos = distinct_values.index(year)
>         distinct_values_count[pos] = sorted_array.count(year)
> 
> file.close()
```

I get this error:

> IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: Use `line.strip()` which removes the `'\n'` not `line.split('\n')` which creates a one element list which then gets appended making `sorted_array` multi dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

Many things that you are doing can be done more easily in Python. It is certainly easier to deal with a flat list versus the two level list created by splitting each line with `line.split('\n')`. Is there a reason you are doing that?

To create a sorted array of the file contents:

```
with open('/tmp/file') as f:
    sorted_array=sorted(line.strip() for line in f)
```

To get the distinct values, use a set:

```
distinct_values=set(sorted_array)
```

To get the count of distinct values:

```
distinct_value_count=[(e, sorted_array.count(e)) for e in distinct_values]
```

If you want that sorted:

```
distinct_value_count=sorted((e, sorted_array.count(e)) for e in distinct_values)
```

Then:

```
>>> sorted_array
['1977', '1978', '1982', '1983', '1983', '1987', '1988', '1996', '2006', '2011', '2012', '2013']
>>> distinct_values
{'2011', '2006', '1996', '1978', '1977', '1987', '1983', '2012', '1982', '1988', '2013'}
>>> distinct_value_count
[('1977', 1), ('1978', 1), ('1982', 1), ('1983', 2), ('1987', 1), ('1988', 1), ('1996', 1), ('2006', 1), ('2011', 1), ('2012', 1), ('2013', 1)]
```

Or, use a dictionary for the to replace both the need to create a separate set and count, since the keys of a dict are unique also (but unordered):

```
>>> dv_dict={k:sorted_array.count(k) for k in set(sorted_array)}
>>> dv_dict
{'1996': 1, '2011': 1, '1978': 1, '1988': 1, '2013': 1, '1977': 1, '1987': 1, '2006': 1, '2012': 1, '1983': 2, '1982': 1}
```